# Recreating Sharepoint Search Feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

SharePoint search service application was removed.  I am trying to rebuild one for the users.  Problem I am running into is when I try to create a new application pool it fails and says the application pool already exists, and if I try to use an existing app pool I get an error saying that the account does not have permission to run the reconfigure statement.  I have given the service account DB_Owner permissions on all databases, and I have given it Creator and SysAdmin server roles.  Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: is the account in farm administrators group too?

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to include that.  The user account is also a Farm Admin

Comment: Try this. it looks interesting! http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/dont-have-permission-to-run-reconfigure/ also make the user server admin if possible!

Comment: and also this! actually, it will help if you provide exact error message you getting! https://sharepointsoldiers.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/eventid-6398-you-do-not-have-permission-to-run-sp_trace_create/

Comment: Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application. 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): User does not have permission to perform this action. You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement. User does not have permission to perform this action. You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE statement. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection,

Comment: Hey would you mind submitting an answer Vamsi so I can give you credit?  Doing the digging you provided I found a SECOND service account that I was not aware of that had to be granted the permissions to the SQL Databases.

Comment: James, that is nice of you to mention! I am not sure which link that i provided worked for you. Also, it looks like you have some more details you can provide! So, i suggest you post the answer with all the background such what is the purpose of the second service account, etc. It will help future readers! Thanks again!